# Get from 3 inputs and replace at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my working code :

```js
const intro = "you entered the words: ";
const outro = "</br>Thanks";
let input1 = '';
let input2 = '';

$('#inp1, #inp2').on('input', function update(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.id === 'inp1') {
    input1 = e.currentTarget.value;
  } else {
    input2 = e.currentTarget.value;
  }
  $("#disp1").html(intro + '<br>' + input1 + ' and ' + input2 + outro);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 


<textarea id="inp1" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp1"></textarea></br>
</br>
<textarea id="inp2" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp1"></textarea></br>
</br>


<a id="disp1" target="_blank"> </a>
```

As you can see i enter two inputs and it combines them in one string. now i'd like to adapt my code to 3 or 4+ inputs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: As you can see i enter two inputs and it combines them in one string. now i'd like to adapt my code to 3 or 4+ inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to generalize your code so that it works with an arbitrary number of `textarea` elements.

To achieve that, one possibility would be to create an array in your `input` event handler that temporarily stores valid values of each `textarea` in your document by doing something like this:

```
var array = [];

$('textarea').each(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value) {
      array.push(value);
    }
});
```

Once you have this array, you could then use the [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to create a string that has `" and "` between the value of each array item:

```
var displayHTML = intro + '<br>' + array.join(' and ') + outro;
```

Here is a code snippet showing these ideas in a working solution:

```js
const intro = "you entered the words: ";
const outro = "</br>Thanks";

// Select from all "textarea" elements
$('textarea').on('input', function update(e) {
  
  // This array will store valid values from all textarea's
  var array = [];
  
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    
    // If value of this textarea being iterated is valid, then
    // add to the array
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value) {
      array.push(value);
    }
  });

  // Create the display html string, using Array#join to create 
  // a string result of each item joined by " and " string  
  var displayHTML = intro + '<br>' + array.join(' and ') + outro;
  
  $("#disp1").html(displayHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 


<a id="disp1" target="_blank"> </a>
</br>
<textarea id="inp1" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp1"></textarea></br>
</br>
<textarea id="inp2" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp1"></textarea></br>
</br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></br>
</br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></br>
</br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></br>
</br>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes your understanding for my request is correct, the example i provided contains the function i'm working with on another project, would it be possible to apply my request on the same function i provided please? something like "$('#inp1, #inp2,#inp3,#inp4').on('input', function update(e) {...     thank you

Comment: Great! When you say "apply my request", what do you mean? Do you only have a specific set of element id's that you want this to work with?

Comment: I have many textareas each has its own id, and i'd like to use the function update() as i provided in the code snippets, for example for 4 inputs, the function will start with "$('#inp1, #inp2,#inp3,#inp4').on('input', function update(e) ... thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't think I quite understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks, i eventually succeded by puting alot of else ifs in there. have a nice day

Comment: @BinGeek ok - have a great day also :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do the job

```js
const intro = "you entered the words: <br>";
const outro = "<br>Thanks";
let input = '';


$(document).on('input', 'textarea', function update(e) {
  $(this).each(function() {
    input += e.currentTarget.value + ' and ';
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
  $("#disp1").html(intro + '<br>' + input + ' and ' + outro);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inp">
  <textarea id="inp1" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp1"></textarea>
  <textarea id="inp2" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp2"></textarea>
  <textarea id="inp3" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp3"></textarea>
</div>



<a id="disp1" target="_blank"> </a>
```

Comment: This does not actually do the job.